# Compute the Clarke subdifferential of a function

Tags: calculus, optimization, non-smooth-analysis

The Clarke subdifferential of $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$ is a set $[-1, 1]$, and $\{sign(x)\}$ otherwise, just like the ordinary subdifferential because of convex. Now for \begin{equation}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
|x|/2-x^2/4, \text { if }|x|\leq 1,\\
 1/4,        \text {    otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation} what is the Clarke subdifferential of $g(x)$? I thought the Clarke subdifferential of $g$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\partial g(x)=
\begin{cases} 
\{sign(x)/2-x/2\}, \text{ if } 0<|x|\leq 1,\\
 \{0\}, \text{ if } |x|>1,\\
[-1/2, 1/2], \text{ if }x=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
 Is my understanding correct, particularly at $x=0$?

Comment: Yes, this seems correct

Comment: @madnessweasley Why $g(x)$ is locally Lipschitz continuous from which the Clarke derivative is defined on? $g(x)$ is not convex.

Comment: Any piecewise smooth function is locally Lipschitz continuous

Comment: @madnessweasley What is your defintion of piecewise smooth function? Is there a proof or reference for your assertion? Consider a piecewise smooth function: \begin{equation}f(x)=\begin{cases}L \text{ if } L \leq x \leq 0\\2x \text{ if }0 \leq x \leq L. \end{cases}\end{equation} I don't think the function is locally Lipschitz continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Your notation/definition is inconsistent - I think you meant $f(x) = L$ when $-L \leq x < 0$ and $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 \leq x \leq L$ for some $L > 0$. Of course this function is not locally Lipschitz continuous at $x = 0$ since it isn't even continuous there. A simple and typical definition of piecewise smooth function is that the function is continuous and defined piecewise (like the way you defined it), with each piece being smooth. See [this link](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Piecewise_Continuously_Differentiable_Function) for a simple example of this definition

Comment: @madnessweasley Thanks for spotting a typo. Unfortunately I couldn't edit it now after five times edit. Obviously the definition in the link is much stronger than I previously thought: $f(x)=|x|^{1/3}$ is not piecewise smooth.